# Нужно создать код используя dom

Tags: javascript, dom

Нужно написать скрипт, который для каждого элемента массива ingredients:

Создаст отдельный элемент

. с помощью метода document.createElement().
Добавит название ингредиента как его текстовое содержимое.
Добавит элементу класс item.
После чего вставит все

за одну операцию в список ul#ingredients.

Мой код:

```js
const ingredients = [
  "Potatoes",
  "Mushrooms",
  "Garlic",
  "Tomatos",
  "Herbs",
  "Condiments",
];

const ulEl = document.querySelector(".ingredients");

ingredients.forEach((ingredients) => {
  const listEl = document.createElement("li");
  listEl.classList.add("item");
  listEl.textContent = ingredients;
  console.log(listEl);

  ulEl.append(listEl);
});
```

```html
<ul class="ingredients"></ul>
```

В консоли ошибка и не добавляются в HTML мои li, ul

Comment: Вроятно, нехватало `<ul class="ingredients"></ul>`.. Всё работает

Comment: извините, но не совсем понял где не хватает ?

Comment: На странице... Где ещё то? Я отредактировал Ваш вопрос, смотрите как было и как теперь

Comment: нет, html файл есть, с помощью js нужно создать ul и li , добавив ваше редактирование в js, ничего не поменялось

Comment: Ну так в консоли сейчас нет ошибок и все добавляется.

Comment: @Миша `const ulEl = document.querySelector(".ingredients");` - вы ищите на странице эл-т с классом ingredients.. Его не находит - отсюда ошибка. Если его нет то его надо создавать так же, как Вы это с li делаете.

Comment: ок,спасибо за помощь